# Sublime Text 3 has integrated terminal?

Tags: eclipse, terminal, ide, sublimetext3

I normally use the WebStorm IDE for Node.js and FE JavaScript development. However I was thinking of using Sublime Text 3 since I am running out of computing power on a crappy old Macbook Pro and ST3 should be lighter on memory and CPU.

However, my one hangup is that ST3 doesn't seem to have a command line terminal integration possible. I find this to be a very useful feature that's available in Eclipse and WebStorm.

I did some Googling and I don't see any great terminal integration plugins for ST3, is there such a thing or not?

Here is WebStorm with the terminal integrated:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the ST3 package [REPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL)

Comment: @AlexanderMills Is this question an ad for vs code or something? Every answer, and even the question itself, has a comment from you, the one asking the question, telling people to use vs code instead. There actually _is_ a good package for this in ST3: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below original answer is now outdated; see [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55484753/3403196) by Svish.

---

I was wondering the same thing a while back, and I believe the answer is: **no**.

There's no good terminal integration in ST3, except, maybe, for [Terminal](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminal), which simply takes you *to* the terminal from any given project folder.
Works ok, but not sure how much it really saves.

No way to have it *in the ST3 window* AFAIK.

Comment: that sucks :(  am I the only one that as a result of this discovery find ST3 to be unusable?

Comment: Use VSCode, it's designed around Node.js, from Microsoft, and it has an integrated terminal: https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: This answer is wrong. There's a package, https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus, which allows you to open a terminal both in a tab and _and_ in a panel (like in the screenshot).

Comment: @AlexanderMills yes, in this case, you might actually be the only one. There _is_ a package that adds this functionality, and even if there _wasn't_, it still wouldn't make ST3 "unusable". A terminal built-in to the editor, or ide for that matter, is a nice-to-have feature, it's not critical. If you don't have it, you just use separate regular terminal window instead, which I usually do even when I do have an integrated option.

Comment: I wrote a little plugin that integrates any linux terminal with Sublime. It's not as mature as Terminus but it works very well for me. https://github.com/tobiasrenkin/sublime-console

Answer (score 78):

[Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) does this. Supports both Unix and Windows. Works great.

**In View (on Windows)**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> --> `Terminus: Open Default Shell in Tab (View)`

[image: screenshot 1]

**In Panel (on Unix)**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> --> `Terminus: Open Default Shell in Panel`

Type `exit` to exit and close the terminal opened in a panel.

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: wow! Using this and pudb made my sublime a stronger/faster/more efficient IDE than pycharm. Extremely impressive and the 'per terminal theme adustment'  makes it super easy to find the terminal tab at a glance

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It'd be helpful also if you mention the key bindings (if any) to launch it. EDIT: I found how - https://github.com/randy3k/Terminus#user-key-bindings

Comment: if you open a Terminus panel and then try to search for something (i.e. via cmd-F or cmd-shift-F) it closes the terminus panel. is there any way around this?

Comment: For anyone wondering: this works great in Sublime Text 4 too.

Comment: For high-memory applications, Terminus slows significantly.

Answer (score 13):

I installed the Sublime package [TerminalView](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TerminalView) that can show a terminal window within Sublime in a separate tab.

It works with MacOS or Linux but is no longer actively supported.

[image: TerminalView in SublimeText]

Installation:

1. Open the command palette (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Windows) and find `Package Control: Install Package`
2. Search for `TerminalView` and hit <kbd>Return</kbd> to install.

The terminal windows has a few flaws (at least on macOS) as it seems to conflict with Sublime's keyboard shortcuts. I however use it only to automatically run unit tests when the edited program code changes. Therefore it works just fine. In that case it works best if I show the terminal window below the text editor. You can do so in the menu *View > Layout > Rows: 2*.

Comment: Note: TerminalView needs [Linux-based OS](https://github.com/Wramberg/TerminalView).

Comment: VSCode has a very good terminal extension. That made me abandon Sublime Text.

Comment: Lol. Just migrated from Sublime to VSCode like 3 hours ago.  It feels really good. I am surprised it is a free product!

Comment: Did the same but I had to go back to ST due to the poor tabs management on VSC. Just copy/paste the ST tabs UX and take my money.

Comment: I'd say opposite... if the ST team had a VSCode style editor integration, they could take my money for sure! :) As it is I'm using emacs...

Answer (score 10):

In sublime 3,

1. <kbd>ctrl + shift + p</kbd> search `Package Control: Install Package`
2. Search and install `TerminalView`
3. to set shortcuts,
   go to `Preferences -> Key Bindings`

**on right side Pane** paste this,

```
[
   { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+t"], "command": "terminal_view_open" }
]
```

4. Now <kbd>ctrl+shift+t</kbd> is your shortcuts

Comment: this opens terminal in a separated window. OP wants it to be opened inside of Sublime window as a integrated terminal

Answer (score 7):

I prefer [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus)  and it's the first cross platform terminal for Sublime Text. Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mV0ghkMwTQc) it might help you

[image: Here is Terminus]

Answer (score 5):

I tried Sublime package - TerminalView, quickly realized I couldn't copy paste things. Tried on MacOS.

Terminus(https://github.com/randy3k/Terminus ) looks good to me, it has two options

(i) opens in a tab(view)

(ii) opens also in a panel. (which I prefer most)

Comment: VSCode integrated terminal is much better than ST3. Intellij also has a good one.

Comment: VScode, will give it a try. Recently moved out from Atom.