# Macros/shortcuts for terminal commands from Sublime Text 3

Tags: linux, terminal, sublimetext3

There's this question: [Sublime Text 3 terminal integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439023/sublime-text-3-terminal-integration) but what that user wants is an integrated terminal. I'd be content with something much simpler. I just want to, with some simple key strokes, launch a script/command *in the directory of the currently active file*.

Another great bonus would be if I could associate a specific terminal window with a specific ST3 window (I usually have two subl windows with one corresponding terminal for each on 3-4 different workspaces). I suspect this can be achieved using `xdotool` (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/641683/how-can-i-send-commands-to-specific-terminal-windows) but it would of course be nicer if ST3 was smart enough to do it for me easily.

I tried

```
[
{ "keys": ["shift+ctrl+5"], "shell_cmd": "./script.sh" }
]
```

but it doesn't work -- nothing at all happens.

Answer (score 3):

You can only execute Sublime Text commands from keybindings.

The command used by build systems should work for your use case. It is called `exec`, and accepts a parameter of what shell command to run, and the working directory defaults to the folder that the currently edited file is saved in.

Try:

```
[
    { "keys": ["shift+ctrl+5"], "command": "exec", "args": { "shell_cmd": "./script.sh" } },
]
```

Comment: You can check exec args documentation here https://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/exec.html